# When implementing LoST protocol, how do we unmarshall a geodetic location from a findService request using Java?

Tags: java, jaxb

I understand I have a very specific issue on a protocol that only few people in the world would probably be working on. Thank you in advance for reading and trying to help me with this.

Context:
I am currently implementing the LoST: A Location-to-Service Translation Protocol as described in RFC 5222. In particular, I am working on parsing a FindService request which is an XML document. If you are curious, the schema for that document is found inside the RFC, but not critical to this question.

I am using Java with JAXB.   I have been able to implement various requests using XSDs with no issues so I believe my Maven plugins and code generation methods are correct.

Problem:
My problem is that I'm having trouble unmarshalling a specific type of location that can be found in the FindService request. That type is the "geodetic-2d" location type which is defined by the following additional documentation:

[GEOPRIV Presence Information Data Format Location Object (PIDF-LO) Usage Clarification, Considerations, and Recommendations](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc5491.pdf)
[geoshape profile](http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/profiles/geoshape/0.1.0/)

The error I am getting is that javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.opengis.net/pidflo/1.0", local:"Circle"). Expected elements are <{http://www.opengis.net/gml}ArcByCenterPoint>[...]

Essentially what this message is saying is that the unmarshaller was expecting objects from the gml namespace but found  pidflo instead. The XML object looks like this:

```
<gs:Circle srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
xmlns:gs="http://www.opengis.net/pidflo/1.0"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<gml:pos>
42.5463 -73.2512
</gml:pos>
<gml:radius uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001">
850.24
</gml:radius>
</gs:Circle>
```

This example comes from OpenGIS documentation and is correct.  Notice how there are two namespaces mixed together. "Circle" is indeed from the pidflo namespace and I have verified that the XSDs are correct.

Question:
I would like to know how to unmarshall a geodetic location from a FindService "location" object.

In order to simplify this question, I think if someone can help me unmarshall the Circle XML object shown above, I should be able to resolve my issue with other types.

In order to make this question more practical, consider the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JAXBContext gmlOrCivicContext = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        gmlOrCivicContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(net.opengis.pidflo._1.CircleType.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = gmlOrCivicContext.createMarshaller();
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<CircleType> circle = objectFactory.createCircle(new CircleType());
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(circle, byteArrayOutputStream);

        String x = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
        System.out.println(x);

        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(x.getBytes());
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = gmlOrCivicContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Object unmarshal = unmarshaller.unmarshal(byteArrayInputStream);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When running this program, I am able to marshal and printout the Circle object, but I cannot unmarshall it (even though I'm using exactly the same context!).

Here is the console output for the code shown above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Circle xmlns:ns1="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ns2="http://www.opengis.net/pidflo/1.0"/>

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.opengis.net/pidflo/1.0", local:"Circle"). Expected elements are <{http://www.opengis.net/gml}ArcByCenterPoint>,[...]
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
```

Does anyone have an idea why I am able to marshall the object but not unmarshall it?

If there is any more information I can provide please let me know.

- Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why my JAXB generated classes could marshall XML but not unmarshall it. I thought I would share the answer here in case someone runs in a similar issue working with LoST (and the namespace names it uses).

The issue is in the generated package name for the opengis pidflo geoshape xml namespace: xmlns:gs="http://www.opengis.net/pidflo/1.0".

It gets automatically translated in the following java package name:
net.opengis.pidflo._1.CircleType.class

The leading underscore in "_1" does not work well with Java.

Once the package name was fixed, all the code started working.

I changed my Maven JAXB plugin configuration as to use the "packageName" directive to force the geoshape package to avoid the underscore. I also split code generation on a per-xsd basis to set proper packages for each of them and I used the clearOutputDir directive to avoid each of those executions overriting each other's generated output.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-gml</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>src/main/xsd/geoshape/0.1.0/GML-pidf-lo-shape.xsd</sources>
                        <packageName>net.opengis.pidflo</packageName>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-civic</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>src/main/xsd/civicAddr.xsd</sources>
                        <packageName>ietf.params.xml.ns.pidf.geopriv10.civicaddr</packageName>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-lost</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>src/main/xsd/lost.xsd</sources>
                        <packageName>ietf.params.xml.ns.lost1</packageName>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

Regards,

- Nicolas